# What is the reason to block foo['(arbitraryName)'] when wtih --noImplicitAny?

Tags: typescript

These codes work without --noImplicitAny, but fail with it.

```
var name = 'abc';
document.body.dataset[name] = 1;
var property = document.body.dataset[name];

var o = {};
var name = 'abc';
o[name] = 1;
var property = o[name];
```

I partially understand it because `o['arbitraryName']` is 'implicitly' `any` type. However, why would anyone use it rather than `o.arbitraryName` when there is known typed property? Isn't it OK to allow this, to make "a method to opt-out of typing"? (as [parenthesizing does similar thing for expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9#issuecomment-52347966))

I think there should be some good reasons to block this, and I wonder what they are.

Comment: You can't `o.arbitraryName` with a variable `arbitraryName`, it has to be hardcoded.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Right, and we should do o[arbitraryName] in that case. However, we cannot do it with --noImplicitAny. I wonder why we should block this.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't blocked by the `--noImplicitAny` flag, is is simply brought to your attention so you can "opt-out of typing" by making it an explicit any...

```
var property: any = o[name];
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing last line! Then how can I fix `o[name] = 1` to work? (PS: That fix doesn't work, compiler still says "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.")